# Error: optimizer got an empty parameter list. How can i modify my code?

Tags: python, pytorch

Here is code:

```
class MLP(nn.Module):  
    def __ini__(self):
         super (MLP, self). __init__()  
         self.model=nn.nn.Sequential(  
            nn.Linear(784, 200),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),  
            nn.Linear(200, 200),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(200, 10),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            )

    def forward(self,x):
                x=self.model(x)
                return 
device= torch.device('cuda:0')
net = MLP().to(device)
```

when running these codes

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)
```

I get

> ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list"

I am trying to imitate [this notebook](https://github.com/tsuirak/skills/blob/main/Pytorch/Pytorch_learn_by_dragen1860/lesson25-%E6%BF%80%E6%B4%BB%E5%87%BD%E6%95%B0%E4%B8%8EGPU%E5%8A%A0%E9%80%9F.ipynb).

Comment: i am trying to imitate the example [link]https://github.com/tsuirak/skills/blob/main/Pytorch/Pytorch_learn_by_dragen1860/lesson25-%E6%BF%80%E6%B4%BB%E5%87%BD%E6%95%B0%E4%B8%8EGPU%E5%8A%A0%E9%80%9F.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. Currently your code is equivalent to:

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        pass
```

Here are the issues:

1. Your initializer is named `__init__`.
2. `forward` should return a value, here `x`.
3. Replace `nn.nn.Sequential` with `nn.Sequential`.

---

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super (MLP, self).__init__()  
        self.model = nn.Sequential(  
            nn.Linear(784, 200),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),  
            nn.Linear(200, 200),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(200, 10),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True))

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.model(x)
        return x

device= torch.device('cuda:0')
net = MLP().to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

Comment: thx for you answer. but when i run these new codes. a new problem occurs.AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled. pointed to 'net = MLP().to(device)'

Comment: I'm assuming you are running you are running your code on Colab, if so you need to activate GPU. Go under `Runtime` > `Change Runtime Type` > `Hardware Acceleration` = GPU